# 'list' object has no attribute 'short_name'

Tags: python, list, object

```py
class Nation:
    def __init__(self, short_name, long_name, iso_code, iso_short, iso_long, capital):
        self.short_name = short_name
        self.long_name = long_name
        self.iso_code = iso_code
        self.iso_short = iso_short
        self.iso_long = iso_long
        self.capital = capital

    def to_dictionaries(nation_list):

        my_dictionary_1 = {}
        my_dictionary_2 = {}
        my_dictionary_3 = {}

        for i in [nation_list]:
            my_dictionary_1 = nation_list.short_name
            for j in [nation_list]:
                my_dictionary_2["long_name"] = nation_list.long_name
                my_dictionary_2["iso_code"] = nation_list.iso_code
                my_dictionary_2["iso_short"] = nation_list.iso_short
                my_dictionary_2["iso_long"] = nation_list.iso_long
                my_dictionary_2["capital"] = nation_list.capital
                my_dictionary_3[my_dictionary_1] = my_dictionary_2


    new_nation_1 = Nation("Albania", "Republic of Albania", 8, "AL", "ALB", "Tirana")
    new_nation_2 = Nation("Angola", "Republic of Angola", 24, "AO", "AGO", "Luanda")
    nation_list = [new_nation_1, new_nation_2]
    print(to_dictionaries(nation_list))
```

Any idea why I am having this error instead of:

```
{'Albania': {'long_name': 'Republic of Albania', 'iso_code': 24, 'iso_short': 'AO', 'iso_long':   'AGO', 'capital': 'Luanda'}, 'Angola': {'long_name': 'Republic of Angola', 'iso_code': 24, 'iso_short': 'AO', 'iso_long': 'AGO', 'capital': 'Luanda'}}
```

Comment: Because `nation_list` is a `list` of `Nation` instances ? You only need one for loop

Comment: correct..got any idea on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

`nation_list` is a list object. Since you are iterating the list use `i.short_name`. Also you can simplify the code using `dict.setdefault` and `dict.update`

**Ex:**

```
class Nation:
    def __init__(self, short_name, long_name, iso_code, iso_short, iso_long, capital):
        self.short_name = short_name
        self.long_name = long_name
        self.iso_code = iso_code
        self.iso_short = iso_short
        self.iso_long = iso_long
        self.capital = capital

def to_dictionaries(nation_list):
    result = {}    
    for i in nation_list:
        result.setdefault(i.short_name, {}).update({"long_name": i.long_name, "iso_code": i.iso_code, "iso_short": i.iso_short, "iso_long": i.iso_long, "capital": i.capital})
    return result

new_nation_1 = Nation("Albania", "Republic of Albania", 8, "AL", "ALB", "Tirana")
new_nation_2 = Nation("Angola", "Republic of Angola", 24, "AO", "AGO", "Luanda")
nation_list = [new_nation_1, new_nation_2]
print(to_dictionaries(nation_list))
```

**Output:**

```
{'Albania': {'capital': 'Tirana',
             'iso_code': 8,
             'iso_long': 'ALB',
             'iso_short': 'AL',
             'long_name': 'Republic of Albania'},
 'Angola': {'capital': 'Luanda',
            'iso_code': 24,
            'iso_long': 'AGO',
            'iso_short': 'AO',
            'long_name': 'Republic of Angola'}}
```